# Python read and process file when created

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, eventhandler, python-watchdog

I have used watchdog to listen to a directory and read and process a new file when added. In the `on_created` event, I can get all file names when they are added but processing every file takes some time (several seconds). Processing `file1` should be finished before I get the new file. I tested multi-threading, but couldn't get the correct answer.

How can I handle this problem?

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
def mainfunc(src_path):
    #for runing need 60seconds
class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event):
        t = threading.Thread(target=mainfunc(event.src_path))
```

output:

```
/root/PycharmProjects/f1.nc
finish :at 2020-02-20 13:58:39.352510
/root/PycharmProjects/f2.nc
finish :  at 2020-02-20 13:59:12.404122
```

Comment: `t = threading.Thread(target=mainfunc(event.src_path))` - threads don't start on creation, you should `t.start()` them